# Http error 403 Google Earth Engine in Python

Tags: python, windows-7, google-earth-engine

During 2 days I was installing Google Earth Engine API for Python in Windows 7 and modifying the mapclient.py file because I needed use "import ee.mapclient" instruction for my Python scripts. Finally I got it, it worked with the examples on https://github.com/google/earthengine-api/tree/master/python/examples/py/FeatureCollection. After 15 - 25 it left to work and it showed a message, a exception from the HTTP connection: "HTTP Error 403: Forbidden".

And now if I connect on Google Maps, the it shows a blank map without routes, even if I search locations. It doesn't work in Firefox and Google Chrome. It looks like I can't access to Image Server Images of Google Maps from my computer. It could be a file that created a 403 error to Image Server of Google Maps. What can I do? I've been looking for and I don't find nothing useful. I use Python 3.4.